# INSERT INTO a table using a subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, insert-into

I'm working a query that I've never done and I'm stuck on how to proceed. I would like to be a single insert into command.

The pseudo code what I'm trying to do is like this:

```
For each player 
    insert into CurrentHand table by getting x number of cards needed 
       so all the players have 10 cards in their hands.
```

So if player 1 will get 7 new cards if he has 3 cards in their hands. Play 2 will get 5 new cards if he has 5 cards in their hands.

So far I've gotten to this select statement but it feels like I'm using the wrong approach.

```
DECLARE @MaxHandCount int
SET @MaxHandCount = 10

SELECT Player.PlayerId
    , (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM CurrentHand WHERE PlayerId = Player.PlayerId AND IsUsed = 0) AS CurrentHandCount
    , (@MaxHandCount - (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM CurrentHand WHERE PlayerId = Player.PlayerId AND IsUsed = 0)) AS NeededHandCount
    , CardId
FROM Player, AvailableCard
WHERE Cardid IN (SELECT CardId FROM CurrentHand WHERE IsUsed = 0)
ORDER BY PlayerId
```

The table structure looks like:

```
Player
  - PlayerId

AvailableCard
  - CardId
  - CardValue

CurrentHand
  - PlayerId
  - CardId
  - IsUsed
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `IsUsed` flag? What version of SQL Server do you use? Please tag the question properly.

Comment: The server is MS Sql Server 2012. The purpose of IsUsed is to track which cards have been played already so that the previous played cards are not selected again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was very interesting. Here is my solution to "deal" the needed cards. Please read the commends in the code. This only does the select but I believe you can figure out the insert yourself. Check out the [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f5016/21/0) too.

```
-- for each card in player's hand assign a sequence number
with cte_currenthand as
(
  select PlayerId, 
    rank() over(partition by PlayerId order by CardId) CardSeq
  from CurrentHand
  where IsUsed = 0
)
-- for each player generate a sequence 1..10
, cte_maxhand as
(
select p.PlayerId, x.seq
from Player p
cross join (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) x(seq)
)
-- get cards the players need and assign them new sequence numbers
-- basically cte_maxhand minus cte_currenthand
, cte_needed as
(
  select mh.PlayerId, row_number() over(order by mh.seq) seq
  from cte_maxhand mh
  left join cte_currenthand ch 
    on ch.CardSeq = mh.seq
    and ch.PlayerId = mh.PlayerId
  where ch.CardSeq is null
)
-- generate a random sequence on remaining cards
, cte_deal as
(
  select CardId, row_number() over(order by CHECKSUM(NewId())) seq
  from AvailableCard ac 
  where not exists (
    select *
    from CurrentHand ch
    where ch.CardId = ac.CardId
    )
)
-- deal the cards
select n.PlayerId, d.CardId
from cte_needed n
inner join cte_deal d on d.seq = n.seq
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. That turned out to be a lot more complicated than I though it would. Then again simple things usually end up that way.

Comment: @KathyJudd I'm glad I could help. But I still think you would be better off implementing this in your application layer not in database. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Sample table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cards](
    [player] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [number] [int] NOT NULL
    )
```

Sample data:

```
insert into cards values ('p1',3)
insert into cards values ('p2',5)
insert into cards values ('p3',4)
insert into cards values ('p4',2)
```

Insert:

```
insert into cards
select player,10-sum(number) as number
from cards
group by player
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
DECLARE @MaxHandCount int
SET @MaxHandCount = 10

SELECT Player.PlayerId
    , Count(CardID) AS CurrentHandCount
    , @MaxHandCount - Count(CardID)  AS NeededHandCount
    , CardId
FROM Player
join CurrentHead on Player.PlayerID = CurrentHead.PlayerID
WHERE IsUsed = 0
Group by Player.PlayerID
ORDER BY PlayerId
```